# PHP Script that allow file dynamic link generation

Tags: php, email, dynamic, hyperlink

I have on server side folder with the .zip files. I don't want these files would be accessible from direct link (http://mywebsite.com/intel/tb/wb036333/.zip). Script should generate dynamic link to *.zip files and generated link should disappear after 13 hours left. One of the required parameters before dynamic link generation is to enter a valid email address.

Help me please with the script.

```
<?
$dir_open = opendir('.');

while(false !== ($filename = readdir($dir_open))){
  if($filename != "." && $filename != ".."){
    $link = "<a href='./$filename'> $filename </a><br />";
    echo $link;
  }
}

closedir($dir_open);
?>
```

Comment: Do you have a database or some sort of storage to link the codes with the datacreated and the file they're associated with?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do the e-mail veryfication, u must code the simpliest form, you can google it.

To do disappearing after 13 hours, you can take two ways:
 1. Just move the file after 13 hours to closed from users folder.
 2. Dissalow opening the file by file attributes.
Both ways can be performed through CRON, or be coded in your script and executed while users open pages

If your question is about coding all the interface, i think you won't get the answer here.

Comment: First priority is make file would not be accessible from direct link (http://mywebsite.com/intel/tb/wb036333/.zip). How to do it?

Comment: @MichaelT, your need to specify access restrictions to your file. chmod() will help: [link]http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php 
Read manual and perceive what mode (number) do you need. To make your file non-accesible, u can use, for example 0600.